# Repeat control refresh

Tags: xpages, repeat

Is there a easiest way to update repeat control data , What I want to do is facebook like activity stream (news feed) in a repeat control.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following CSJS code to your XPage. Set the interval value in milliseconds you'd like to refresh your repeat control (instead of 5000 = 5 seconds in example):

```xml
<xp:scriptBlock
    id="scriptBlockRefresh">
    <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[
            setInterval(function() {
                XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:repeatControlId}", {})
            }, 5000)
        ]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: Don't forget that this can have some side effects: Other Partial Refreshs are blocked during the refresh of the Repeat control. Adding a *XSP.allowSubmit()* can avoid this.

Comment: I would suggest not to mess up your xpages with scripblocks. add jquery and do all your refresh in a scriptlibrary

Comment: @ThomasAdrian: For larger code blocks this is correct. But for this one liner it is useless, beacause you would need to call it from another scriptblock (to get the the id the component).

Comment: I see your point but the id can easily be found using css selectors $("[id$='id_ending_with']")

Comment: @ThomasAdrian: While you can do the same with *dojo.query('[id$="id_ending_with"]')*, it is still not a good idea to externalize three lines of javascript code in an external library. The time wasted downloading an extra file would counteract any benefit gained from caching the file later. See http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/when-to-use-inline-javascript